# Do I need to keep the iPhoto Library.migratedphotolibrary

Tags: macos, photos

In my `Pictures` directory I have `Photos Library.photoslibrary` and `iPhoto Library.migratedphotolibrary`.

When I open Photos all my images from `iPhoto` on Mavericks appear to be there.
Do I need to keep the `iPhoto Library.migratedphotolibrary`?